# Get Facebook comment likes / reactions count

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-apps

After Facebook API changes in recent weeks (https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/04/restricting-data-access/), is there any possibility to get reactions / likes on public posts?

I need to get a lot of status / comments / reactions (anonymised) from some public Facebook news page, e.g. CNN, Daily Mail etc. for educational purpose only - for my schoolwork. So I'm talking about data that can be seen by any Facebook user.

At first I tried Graph API Explorer, but it doesn't provide likes. After a while, I found out it is possible with an app. It worked for a moment, but the next day after I started getting the data, Facebook blocked it due to Cambridge Analytica scandal - I get this error now:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Access to this data is temporarily disabled for non-active apps or apps that have not recently accessed this data due to changes we are making to the Facebook Platform. https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/205942813488872/",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200,
      "fbtrace_id": "ElMgcZXjgMt"
   }
}
```

My app is only "In Development" mode, and is not planned to be made public, I created it only for this single purpose - big data analysis homework.

Regarding Pages API, Facebook wrote on 4th of April: "So starting today, all future access to the Pages API will need to be approved by Facebook." However, they did not mention how to do it.

Could someone help me what should I do? I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: You would have to submit your app for review, once the review process resumes (it is currently on hold.) Although I doubt that Facebook will approve your app for such a purpose to begin with.